# TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not list

Tags: python, pygame, surface

This is my code and I was trying to make a rectangle:

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
color = [255,20,78]
black = [0,0,0]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Rectangle")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    screen.fill(color)
    pygame.draw.rect(color, black, [400,300,10,10])
    pygame.display.update()
```

I don't understand what the error means with Surface
Can someone please help me?
Any help appreciated!
Oh and please do not swear to me, I am still a program noob.
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hugo\Desktop\Pygame\game - kopie.py", line 15, in <module>
    pygame.draw.rect(color, black, [400,300,10,10])
TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in line

`pygame.draw.rect(color`

Where color is list.

[draw.rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) need `Surface` as first argument.

> pygame.draw.rect() draw a rectangle shape rect(Surface, color, Rect,
>   width=0) -> Rect Draws a rectangular shape on the Surface. The given
>   Rect is the area of the rectangle. The width argument is the thickness
>   to draw the outer edge. If width is zero then the rectangle will be
>   filled.
>
> Keep in mind the Surface.fill() method works just as well for drawing
>   filled rectangles. In fact the Surface.fill() can be hardware
>   accelerated on some platforms with both software and hardware display
>   modes.

Please pass `Surface` as first argumen.